# Split string based off multiple possible deminiters but keep delimiters

Tags: python

I am cleaning addresses. I am looking to strip everything after specific words (avenue, ave, road, place, etc etc etc).

I was looking at doing something like this but I believe this will return everything before the word. That means "1 first avenue" would return "1 first".

How can I append this (or do it differently?) so that it would return everything up to AND INCLUDING the pattern words?

```
patterns = ["ave", "avenue", "road", "street" etc etc etc]
reduce(lambda s, pat: s.split(pat, 1)[0], patterns, string)
```

Comment: This does not sound efficient, but you could loop through the `patterns` array, and do `id = s.split.index(patterns[i])` then `string = s[:id]` then finally combine it back into a string with `return ' '.join(string)` but it sounds pretty inefficient imo. Could probably optimize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways to achieve this. If the `reduce` here has a significene, this is one way to keep the answer within the `lambda`:

```
patterns = ["ave", "avenue", "road", "street"]
string = 'queen ave west'
reduce(lambda s, pat: s[:s.find(pat)+len(pat)] if s.find(pat) > 0 else s, patterns, string)
```

But a better solution maybe through the use of regular expressions. This combines all of your possible "patterns" into a single regular expression and runs the whole thing once through python's regular expression engine:

```
import re
patterns = ["ave", "avenue", "road", "street"]
regex = r'(.*)(' + '|'.join(patterns) + r')(.*)'
string = 'queen ave west'
re.sub(regex, r'\1\2', string)
```

If you're applying this to multiple addresses, you can optimize the code by compiling the regular expression first then using the compiled regex on each address that you're trying to clean up:

```
import re

patterns = ["ave", "avenue", "road", "street"]
regex = re.compile(r'(.*)(' + '|'.join(patterns) + r')(.*)')
strings = ['queen ave west', 'should stay the same']
sanitized_strings = (regex.sub(r'\1\2', string) for string in strings)
```

Now sanitized_strings contains cleaned up version of strings. You can loop over sanitized_strings with a for loop and print them or do anything else required. Note that the way the regular expression is designed, the whole string will match the first group if none of the words in `patterns` is present. Therefore, if none of the words is present, it will keep the string unchanged, like you requested.

I'm not sure that those are the exact semantics you're looking for. For example, do you really want to return 'queen ave' for 'queen ave west'. Also beware that all of the solutions mentioned so far do not take into account when one of the patterns is in the name of the street, which is very likely if your patterns inlcude the abbreviation 'st' or for example in Toronto, there's a road called 'Avenue Road'. The answers to those quesitons depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How can I turn your second solution into a loop so that it will try this on the address and if it fails it will just keep the address as it previously was?

Comment: @hleggs updated the answer with an example and more explanation. It already does what you want, it will keep the string the same if the words are not present.

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect implementation!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want.

```
pattern = ['ave', 'street', 'road']
address = 'Imaginary ave, Fantasy Island'

for i in pattern:
    if i in address:
        print address[:address.find(i) + len(i)]
```

or if there are a list of addresses

```
print [address[:address.find(i) + len(i)] for i in pattern if i in address]
```

Comment: In the second example should be `address` instead of `string` at the end.

Comment: First and foremost i'd like to thank you for the quick response. Let me be more specific and hopefully you can let me know if this implementation would work. I am reading addresses 1 by 1 from a file and I need to format the address prior to doing other stuff with it. So for each line I would use that nested loop that you included in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This would work for searching for a specific *sub-string* in a string, I used the string `index()` method (however, as other users have pointed out there are multiple ways to solve this problem), which is why there is a try/except block. The  `index()` method returns an error if the sub-string is not found.

```
def strip_address(string):
    patterns = ["ave", "road", "street"]
    final_address = ''

    for pattern in patterns:
        try:
            if not string.index(pattern): continue

            # The tail-index of the pattern in the string
            last_index = len(pattern) + string.index(pattern)

            final_address = string[:last_index] # parsed address
            return final_address

        except ValueError:
            pass
```

**Test:**

```
string = "1 first street 213322"
> '1 first street'

string1 = "1023 sunset road Extra Text here"
> '1023 sunset road'

string2 = "23 applewood ave Apt.1241"
> '23 applewood ave'
```

Comment: I would invert that if statement and make it `continue`, rather than indenting all the real code in more

Answer (score 0):

you can use this compact way

```
print reduce (lambda s,x : str(s.split(x)[0]) if (str(s.split(x)[0]) == s) else str(s.split(x)[0]) + x,patterns)
```

full example

```
patterns = ["ave", "ave", "road" ]
string = "1 first avenue"
patterns.insert(0,string)
print reduce (lambda s,x : str(s.split(x)[0]) if (str(s.split(x)[0]) == s) else str(s.split(x)[0]) + x,patterns)
```

the idea is that we filter with reduce to know when to readd the delimiter word