# How to keep the delimiters in place when split a string with multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"([?.;])")

ss = re.split(p, 'This is a test? This is a test?good.bad')

for s in ss:
    print(s)
```

The result is:

```
This is a test
?
 This is a test
?
good
.
bad
```

I hope the result would be:

```
This is a test?
This is a test?
good.
bad
```

Why does it put the delimiter on another line?

EDIT:
I think I understand why it did that. The question is how to produce the result I want.

Comment: Instead of `split()`, I recommend you use `indexOf()` and `substring()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Could you give an answer?

Comment: You can simply concatenate the even elements to the preceding elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string based off multiple possible deminiters but keep delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107752/split-string-based-off-multiple-possible-deminiters-but-keep-delimiters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment said you *must* use the pattern `p`.  Here's a way to join the pairs up after a split.  `zip_longest` ensures an odd pairing works out by returning `None` for the second element, which is converted to an empty string if present.

```
import re
from itertools import zip_longest

p = re.compile(r"([?.;])")

ss = re.split(p, 'This is a test? This is a test?good.bad')

for a,b in zip_longest(ss[::2],ss[1::2]):
    print(a+(b if b else ''))
```

Output:

```
This is a test?
 This is a test?
good.
bad
```

Comment: Actually this is more elegant than mine.

Comment: @Błotosmętek I think `findall` is a better solution. The restriction is odd.

Answer (score 2):

You can join back the delimiters and preceding items:

```
 ss = re.split(p, 'This is a test? This is a test?good.bad')
 result = [ a+b for a, b in zip(ss[::2], ss[1::2]) ] + (ss[-1:] if len(ss) % 2 else [])
```

Comment: ['Th', 'is', ' i', 's ', 'a ', 'te', 'st', '? ', 'Th', 'is', ' i', 's ', 'a ', 'te', 'st', '?g', 'oo', 'd.', 'ba'] result

Comment: Nice! I get ['This is a test?', ' This is a test?', 'good.'] It only misses the last 'bad'

Comment: Ah yes, I assumed even number of items in `ss`. Fixed.

Comment: Not quite right. It gives an empty '' if 'bad' is removed from the orignal string. You can test.

Comment: Well, if there;s a dot after `good`, there's an empty string after the dot…This can be avoided using additional check: `result = [ a+b for a, b in zip(ss[::2], ss[1::2]) ] + (ss[-1:] if ss[-1] else []) if len(ss) % 2 else []
`